# Using a string to write code in C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm wondering if there is a way to take a string with an output that names a function to call and then call that function without writing a bunch of if or switch statements. To be more specific, I have a number of objects all inheriting from an abstract base class which has a function called `getType();` which returns a `string` saying their type:

```
virtual const string getType()
```

I have a list of `Base *` all pointing to derived objects, but some of the functions in the derived object cannot be called using just a `Base *`. So I was planning on asking the object what type it was, and then dynamically casting to that type, and then calling its function. So I was wondering if there is a way, to take a string and use that string to be interpreted as code by the compiler?

I know my methodology might be a little sloppy on wanting to dynamically cast to the derived class, but I still want to know if I can have a string be interpreted as code, and would love to hear better ideas.

Comment: You explain that you're using downcasting to call specialized functions on certain types, but it's not clear how that requires looking up a function from a string.

Comment: Maybe using some `std::map`s?

Comment: Take a look at `decltype` and `boost::signals2`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not believe what you are wanting can be done. The object pointed to by the base pointer should be able to send a message to all its methods not just the virtual one. I cant say for sure, because you haven’t posted any code, but I think you may have a problem with your access level modifiers for the methods in your sub-classes.